# Changing the half background color of a beamer frame?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, backgrounds

Is it possible to change the half of the beamer frame background color perfectly (no margins), as shown in the picture: [image] without using the above image as background. Maybe by using tikz or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to **@AlexG**

using `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}`

The Minimal file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\fill [color=orange!80] (0.5\paperwidth,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
\end{tikzpicture}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}
\begin{frame}
Not background
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**OR:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[orange!80] (current page.north east) rectangle (current page.south);
\end{tikzpicture}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}
\begin{frame}
Not background
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 4):

With TikZ it is easily done:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{\xusebox{graphics for bg}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xlrbox}{graphics for bg}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \definecolor{bgcolor}{rgb}{1,0.753,0}
    \fill [color=bgcolor] (0.5\paperwidth,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{xlrbox}

\begin{frame}
Slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Slide 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Slide 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked.