# How to use several beamer (slide) templates in one document?

Tags: beamer, templates, naming

Maybe this is an obvious question, but I need some help defining slide templates.

I would like to make my own beamer template and have the option to use several slide templates in one document. One of the slide templates I would like to be a half coloured slide. To make such a slide, I use tikz, as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513593/changing-the-half-background-color-of-a-beamer-frame). Contrary to the post I linked, I don't want this to be the default slide, because I want to define several. Changing `setbeamertemplate` to `defbeamertemplate` does not work.

Am I right in thinking that "background canvas" is the name of this template? How do I choose for each beamer frame what template to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare several `defbeamertemplate` and restict their use to only one or several frames enclosing them into `{...}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{vertical color}[1]
{
\color{#1}\rule{.5\paperwidth}{\paperheight}
}

\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{horizontal color}[1]
{
\color{#1}\rule{\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

{\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical color]{red}
\begin{frame}
Not background
\end{frame}
}

{
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[horizontal color]{green}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]